# Should each end user account get their own table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, user-accounts, connection

n00b mysql question:

If i have a table with all end-user names and Id's and I want to keep track of each users's connections, should each end-user get their own table?

e.g.

end user A is connected to User B, User C and User D;  should there be a separate table, just for user A, that has a list:

```
User B  |    84746
User C  |    94837
User D  |    03265
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest against it -- do not create multiple tables that will need to be the result of queries (e.g. SELECT * from `(CONCAT(...))`).  Instead create a table that maps end users with their connections:

```
 id (primary key) | endUser  | connectedUser | connections
 ---------------------------------------------------------
 1                | User A   | User B        | 84746
 2                | User A   | User C        | 94837
 3                | User A   | User D        | 03265
```

index the endUser column for faster access, and you should be set.

Answer (score 1):

No, use one table.  That's what databases are for :-)
Otherwise, you will wind up with tons of tables (if you have a lot of users).  And even if you don't expect a lot of users, that's not the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you could possibly manage having a variable number of tables, but you would lose all relations that way.  You should add *one* table for the relationships:

```
CREATE TABLE Relationships (
    userOwnerID,
    userFriendID
);
```